# Trying to send Byte Array Images in an email body

Tags: asp.net-mvc

When i am trying to send byte array images as an email body, Its not working. It always sends like an empty email body. Is there any way to send byte array images as an email body(Not like an attachment)?
       I have face this issue in both gmail & outlook. Help me to fix this issue. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: And how are you trying to send it?

Comment: Through SMTP mail sending using MVC.

Comment: Please provide some code :)

Answer (score 0):

Add in your email body this:

```
<img src="cid:imageRef"/>
```

That'll be your image reference, which you need to include. To do that, you can use MailMessage mail object...

```
Dim mail As New MailMessage()
mail.Attachments.Add(New Attachment(New MemoryStream(embedImage), imageName))
mail.Attachments(0).ContentId = "imageRef"
```

where embedImage is `Byte()` and imageName a `String`

Answer (score 0):

from byte array you can send it as image in email body, please ref this link

https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Upload-and-display-Image-without-saving-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

and try creating image url as shown in this link.